# How to put background <img> on the top of the <div> "room"? without touching text inside it

Tags: html, css

I have background img, its just line with block of random colors `height 10px` and i need to put that `background` line on top of `div` "room", by default it stays inside of text within `div`, i thought it'd be better if i just put it on `div` over the other one with text but teacher says it's a bad thing having EMPTY div's so...

Here's my code(i started 3weeks ago, so im very new here)

```
.background{
   background: url(../img/background.png) repeat-x;
   min-height: 70px;
   font-size: 16px;}

<div class="background">
  <div class="text">
     <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've trying using paddings and margins to move background.I am asking for your advice or solutions for this question, thank you

Comment: `background-position: top center` will put it at the top of the div. Also I've never heard of empty divs being a bad thing. In the context of your class, ok, but in the real world empty divs are fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Remember no question is stupid, as long as it follows the guidelines ;) Now let me get this straight: you want to have an image on top of your text? If that is the case, why not use an `img` tag and `position:absolute` it where ever you want?

Comment: @Ant Hello Ant(:D?) i've tried it but when i shrink my monitor width it breaks apart, and teacher said "This line img should be background (not img) if i use it then i probably get minus 0.1-0.5 score points

Comment: @David Wow it worked pretty well, my brain could'nt think about this solution thank you very much, now i can sleep well Xd

Answer (score 0):

Empty divs are technically not harming anyone and a div containing just a background-image is a common thing. Still I would also say, that in this case the extra div is not needed, and then it's a good practice to keep your code clean and flat.

You can actually even handle it just with the p tag and not using any div at all.

```
p {
    padding-top: 10px; /* extra padding on top to contain the image */
    background-size: 100% 10px; /* 10px for height to fit in the padding and not overlap the text */
    background-position: top;
    background-image: url(example-image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If you need to keep the aspect ratio, then set the background-size to auto 10px and use background-repeat: repeat-x.